# Выборка нужных столбцов по результатам подзапроса

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Можно ли указать в SELECT набор столбцов, который будет вычисляться на основе другого подзапроса.

Я хочу выбрать из нескольких таблиц, только те колонки, что удовлетворяют условию подзапроса.

Я получаю список интересующих меня атрибутов (колонок):

```
SELECT DISTINCT string_agg(p.name, ', ' ) FROM attributeparams a JOIN persistentobject p on a.attribute = p.id JOIN attribute at on at.id = p.id
 WHERE a.objtype IN (1,2,3) AND someparam = true;
```

Хотелось бы вставить результат этого подзапроса в другой SELECT

```
SELECT v.id, (подзапрос выше) FROM ... куча таблиц c join
```

но postgres не воспринимает это как исполняемый код, а воспринимает, как одну колонку...

Comment: Лучше поясните конкретным примером. Таблица, данные, результат, объяснение. Сейчас - маловменяемо.

Comment: Поправил описание

Comment: Ааа... не, это только [динамическим SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ecpg-dynamic.html).